# how do I make elements not move when other elements do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have some image elements that when hovered on, scale up, however, this causes some other elements to move, which i dont want happening.

I have tried things like `float: right` which work, but dont fit for my website, since it's margined and centered.

here is a simpled version of my site:

```css
body {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
  }

img{
    max-width: 15%;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform-origin: top;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;
}

img:hover{
    max-width: 17%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(110%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tazzadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/65/2013/11/dummy-image-square.jpg">
<img src="https://www.tazzadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/65/2013/11/dummy-image-square.jpg">
<img src="https://www.tazzadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/65/2013/11/dummy-image-square.jpg">
```

Comment: It’s the max width that is causing the layout jitter. Not your CSS transform. Do not change max width on hover and that’ll solve your problem.

Comment: Capitalizing of "i" and beginning sentences with capital letters would help this post. Also using "don't" instead of "dont".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: scale(110%)` without changing any sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
img:hover{
max-width: 17%;
cursor: pointer;
transform: scale(110%);
}
```

use:

```
img:hover{
cursor: pointer;
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I think that'll do it.